# SED/AWK: Add a string to multiple files matched by regex value from another source file

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, grep

I have a single source file which has multiple entries of this format:

`some_id: some string`

And a bunch of `.txt` files in different folders that have strings that are identified by id

`id="some_id"`

How do I parse the source file in a way so that each string in `.txt` file which has `id` matching one of source file be added a new parameter like so

`id="some_id" some_param="some string"`

which is taken from value of corresponding source file ID

**Notes**

- There can be multiple IDs in same file
- There are never duplicated IDs in any file
- They are never located on the same line
- `some_param` is a literal
- it does't matter where to add new `some_param="string"` as long as it is on the same line and spaced out

Some sample

**source.yml**

```
apples: Apples are very tasty
grapes: Grapes kind of ok
trees: Gain mass from CO2
strawberry: Yummy
```

**fruits/foo.txt**

```
This is some plain text
Toreplace id="apples" string contains
The most vitamin-rich berry is id="strawberry"
```

**fruits/strange/grapes.txt**

```
And id="grapes" the
```

**questionable/trees.txt**

```
Or id="tress"
```

Given this sample, script should turn **fruits/foo.txt** into:

```
This is some plain text
Toreplace id="apples" string contains some_param="Apples are very tasty"
The most vitamin-rich berry is id="strawberry" some_param="Yummy"
```

Comment: elaborate your question: 1) could be there multiple ids in one file? 2) could they be located on the same line. Post some testable fragment

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest updated, not sure what you meant by testable fragment though.

Comment: Where does the `some_param`  come from, or is it a literal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Complex **`Grep`** + GNU **`Awk`** solution:

The crucial `awk` script content, let's say `add_param_by_id.awk`:

```
#!/bin/awk -f
BEGIN{ FS=":[[:space:]]+" }
NR==FNR{ a[$1] = $2; next }
match($0, /\<id="([^"]+)"/, b) && b[1] in a{ 
    sub(/\<id="[^"]+"/, "& some_param=\042"a[b[1]]"\042") 
}1
```

---

The main commands:

```
export pat="($(cut -d':' -f1 source.yml | paste -s -d'|'))"
grep -ElZr "\<id=\"$pat\"" --include=*.txt | xargs -0 -I{} sh -c \
'awk -f add_param_by_id.awk source.yml "$1" > "/tmp/$$" && mv "/tmp/$$" "$1"' _ {}
```

---

- `pat` - variable containing regex alternation group with identifiers i.e. `(apples|grapes|trees|strawberry)`
- `grep -ElZr id=\"$pat\" --include=*.txt` - prints all filenames which were matched for any of the specified identifiers

---

Example file content after processing:

```
This is some plain text
Toreplace string contains id="apples" some_param="Apples are very tasty"
The most vitamin-rich berry is id="strawberry" some_param="Yummy"
```

Comment: RomanPerekhrest I'm a bit sorry, I have overlooked the complexity of the source files. Is there a way to modify the `regex` to actually include every line, white space and character that is after the match `n` up until (and excluding) id match `n+1` ? Like here https://pastebin.com/KbuBJvbC

Comment: @knitevision, NEW conditions is a pretext for a NEW question

Comment: that would be a duplicated question and closed for sure I suppose :(

Answer (score 1):

With certain caveats, such as "no strange characters in filenames", and "no `/` characters in matching or substitution data values" this should work for you. It's not terribly efficient, in that it makes one pass through every file it can find for each line in the YAML file, but to fix that I would want more information about the relative size of the YAML file to the number of target files.

```
while IFS=: read -r id sp
do
    id="id=\"$id\"" sp="some_param=\"${sp:1}\""

    find . -type f -name '*.txt' |
        while IFS= read -r file
        do
            sed -i "/\<$id/s/$/ $sp/" "$file"
        done
done <source.yml
```

Comment: _"no / characters in matching or substitution data values"_... it's a lot more than that, you'll have to do some serious escaping if you want that `sed` command to work with arbitrary input (imagine what happens if `some_param` contains `&`), not to mention that two nested `while..read` loops to process text may result in the operator falling asleep... Also, I'm not sure why using `*` as a starting point for `find`...

Comment: @don_crissti, yes I know, thanks. The (other solution)[https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/409591/100397] here also fails on "unintended" RE matches. I was trying to highlight shortcomings of this solution. Perhaps I'd have been better to keep quiet as it will satisfy the question asked here.